# Magento 2: Call backend before display payment method on checkout page

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I have my custom payment `my_offsite_custom_payment` method and onepage-checkout page modified in `xml` file below.

Before I display that payment method on checkout page I need to get extra data from backend to check what other options have merchant. After getting that data from backend I need to display it with that Payment option.

Could anybody help me to achieve that?

**checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Custom_Payment::css/offsite-custom.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="payment-custom" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">My_Payment/js/view/payment/custom</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">                                                                      
                                                                        <item name="my_offsite_custom_payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>                                                                        
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change load order, you would need to add sequence in your Custom Module  etc/module.xml file. And add '**Magento_Backend**' there.

Check devdocs here, that how does it load sequence work :
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue by creating `observer` with type: `sales_order_place_after` in `etc/events.xml`

```
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="custom_end_order" instance="MyModule\Payment\Observer\CustomPaymentObserver" />
</event>
```

than I implemented in observer:

```
$paymentInfo->setAdditionalInformation(['stuff here']);
```

this additional information was available in javascript.